# How do I check if a string contains ANY numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to validate an input for the user's name. So far I can prevent them entering only numbers and the prompt is repeated using a while loop. How can I stop a string containing letters and numbers being accepted?

This is what I have so far:

```
name = ""
name = input("Please enter your name:")
while name == "" or name.isnumeric() == True:
    name = input("Sorry I didn't catch that\nPlease enter your name:")
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) and [`str.isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit):

```
>>> any(str.isdigit(c) for c in "123")
True
>>> any(str.isdigit(c) for c in "aaa")
False
```

In your case:

```
while name == "" or any(str.isdigit(c) for c in name):
    name = input("Sorry I didn't catch that\nPlease enter your name:")
```

Alternatively you can use [`str.isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha):

> Return true if all characters in the string are alphabetic and there is at least one character, false otherwise.
>
> For 8-bit strings, this method is locale-dependent.

I'd use it like this to validate stuff like `"Reut Sharabani"`:

```
while all(str.isalpha(split) for split in name.split()):

    # code...
```

What it does is split the input by whitespace and make sure each part is alphabetic letters only.

Comment: Why not just use `string.isalpha()`?

Comment: @Ben only because of the title, but you're right :) Added.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Could you show me how to incorporate str.isalpha() into my while loop? I used your first example Reut but like you said it still allows strings such as "£*^$&^" which aren't acceptable names

Comment: The last line of the answer is just for that. Make sure you understand what it does.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply aha but I just solved it now thanks for the help :)